# Subprocess popen buffer size

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, buffer, popen

How can i set the size of a popen buffer or clear it? I have two scripts: ty2.py just do two prints

```
#import sys
a, b = b'123', '123'
print(a)
print(b)

#print(sys.getsizeof(a)) #36
#print(sys.getsizeof(b)) #52
```

and t1.py call t2.py script using popen

```
import subprocess as sp
#pipe = sp.Popen(['stdbuf', '-o0', '-i0', '-e0', 'python3', '-u', 't2.py'], stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=2, universal_newlines=True)
pipe = sp.Popen(['python3', 't2.py'], stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=2)
#pipe.stdout.flush() #also doesn't work
print(pipe.stdout.read())
```

output: b"b'123'\n123\n"

my data should come real-time and i need to output only last print. Is it possible? There is no difference if i set bufsize 0, 1, 2 or even 200: it reads both prints (i know, that 0 means no buffer, but what i see is full buffering). I need to limit it. stdbuf and -u also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really want the output as a byte type?

Comment: @GuiGWR yes, i need convert it to numpay array afrer. Data are a raw images.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the last print only you can try:

```
   pipe = subprocess.Popen([<YOUR COMMANDS>], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, 
   universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0]

   print(pipe.rstrip().split('\n')[-1])
```

When `universal_newlines=True`, the stream will be a text stream, otherwise it is a byte stream. I'm not sure if you want that option.

Comment: the provlem is that i get a raw images, so i ned it in bytes. Therefore it is not line-separated. Also i need to read it in real-time, so the process must be running.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence in your question: "my data should come real-time and i need to output only last print". You mean you want only the `print(b)` part?

Comment: GuiGWR no, this case is just a simple example of problems i faced with. In my real application i get raw bytes, not line-separated strings